# Android: change layout.xml in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have two fragments side by side. When I do an action on the left fragment I want the right fragment to change. It works as long as the layout.xml of the right fragment is not changed. What I want is to define a number of layouts, e.g. layout1.xml, layout2.xml, and so Depending what happens on the left on the right one of these layouts shall be shown. I found http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions but I am not sure if that is the right approach. If not what would be the right way? If it is I struggle a bit with

```
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
```

I need to tell the newFragment that it has now e.g. layout27.xml. How can I do this?

**Edit:**

My main.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<fragment class="com.whatever.OverviewFragment"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:name="com.whatever.OverviewFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

    <fragment class="com.whatever.DetailFragment"
    android:id="@+id/listB"
    android:name="com.whatever.DetailFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The second fragment should be swapped on user actions, for listB I have lets say 5 different layout.xml files.

DetailFragment.java looks basically like this:

```
public  class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container, false);
    }

    //this is called when I do an action in the other fragment
    public void setScreen(int id) {
        //This fragment is one of the 5 possible fragments
        DetailFragment2 newF = new DetailFragment2();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.listB, newF);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do something similar using the fragment arguments to pass which layout to choose

Fragment 1 (control)

```
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putInt("LayoutChoice",i); // i chooses which layout to use on fragment 2
Fragment f = new Fragment2();
f.setArguments(data);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fcontainer, f);
```

Fragment 2 (display)

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    switch( getArguments().getInt("LayoutChoice") ) {
    case 1:
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, container, false);
        break;
    case 2:
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2, container, false);
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

So what you can do is use The fragment transaction manager and on myabe some kind of event (lets assume a button click event) you change the way you want the fragment to look.

For my code i have a tab click on which a new fragment is loaded so what i do is i replace the old fragment with the new one.

```
        RSSFragment rssfrag = new RSSFragment();
        FragmentManager fmi = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ftu = fmi.beginTransaction();
        ftu.replace(R.id.frame_fragment, rssfrag).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

RSSFragment is a class which i am invoking and then using the FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction to replace the fragments.
So you can inflate any fragment for whichever you want

Comment: but how do you tell your rssfrag that it is linked to layout27.xml, somewhere you need to link the object with the layout. I don't see that in your code.

Comment: In my RSSFragment class i have a OncreateView() method which i inflate it with a particular xml like this :

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_fragment, container, false);

Comment: I have an activity showing two fragements. In the code for fragment2 I say then basically replace myself (fragment2) with a new fragment. sounds odd. I tried it: both layouts are above each other... so getting closer but not really what I want...

Comment: Okay so from your question are you trying to say that inside an activity you have two fragments and lets say on some event you want to inflate fragment2 with a different layout and fragment1 to remain the same ?
If so then this is easily available .. in your oncreateview inflate your 2 fragments with some particular layouts and then on the event where you want to change just inflate the other layout with something else by using the replace code i mentioned above

Comment: Android2390 i need help with something simmular but i need more instructions .. like detail cause i dont know much about android code or java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576978/fragment-state-pager-adapter

Comment: Hey Jacob..THe question says it has been removed..Ask the question and i will gladly answer.